# Not sure how to complete this equals method

Tags: java, equals, equals-operator

Could someone help me with this question please? I've tried looking up other examples of this to find what I need to do and keep running into something called and EqualsBuilder, is that what I need to use? Do I need to have it call on equals again if it satisfies neither of the IFs?

The following code contains a class definition and an incomplete method definition. The equals method is used to compare Buildings.
It is intended to return true if Buildings have the same names and number of floors (but are not necessarily the same Building) and false otherwise.

```
public class Building {      
    private String name;      
    private int noOfFloors;

    public boolean equals (Object rhs) {          
        if (this == rhs) { 
            return true; 
        }          
        if (!(rhs instanceof Building)) { 
            return false; 
        }          
        Building b = (Building) rhs;     

        // missing return statement      
    }  
}
```

Comment: you're question contains the answer to your question...

Comment: Compare `this.name` to `b.name` and `this.noOfFloors` to `b.noOfFloors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public boolean equals (Object rhs) {          
    if (this == rhs) { 
        return true; 
    }          
    if (!(rhs instanceof Building)) { 
        return false; 
    }          
    Building b = (Building) rhs;     

    // This is what you're supposed to add. It will return true only if both
    // object's attributes (name and number of floors) are the same
    return this.name.equals(b.name) && this.noOfFloors == b.noOfFloors;
}
```

Comment: I should also have put it that way, way shorter :). Just thought it might be detailed enough for OP. Deserves an upvote anyway

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that you have to test for now is the fields of both objects. If they are equal, then you should return true, if at least one of them is not then you should return false.

Since your fields in that case are `int` and `String`you can use `==` for the integer field and `.equals()` for the String field.

Something like this should do the job just fine:

```
if(this.name.equals(b.name) && this.noOfFloors == b.noOfFloors){
    return true ;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the instanceOf tests you want to compare the fields of the object to the other object. Something like `Objects.deepEquals()` should do the trick for you nicely.

Comment: whoops, meant `deepEquals()`

Comment: Even so, not sure that's the way to go. Since the equals method is not defined i'm quite unsure of what that would give but then again I never usr deepEquals() anyway